# Unreal conditional for future in question

Tags: translation, future, conditional-future, russian

I have a real trouble to properly translate to English following Russian phrase 'У вас будет хоть что-то более интересное, чем это?'. As far as I can understand, it's a question with unreal condition with relation for the future tense.

A rough literal translation would be: 'Will you have at least something which is more interesting than this?', but this translation loose all 'unreal' part and I'm not sure if I used tenses right.

Update: Few people helped me to make it less boring: 'Are you going to have something more interesting than this?'.

How this kind of construction is named in English?

Comment: "When are you likely to have something more interesting than this?" is idiomatic and asks for a prediction, conceding that the person/s asked may not be able to give a totally accurate answer. Language containing / allowing estimates of certainty / probability uses 'modal' devices (here, the string 'be likely to').

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: I can't read the Russian original, but *Come back when you have something more interesting / useful / worthwhile* is an idiomatic response for what *seems* to be the context here. Alternatively, *Tell me something I **don't** know* might qualify as a kind of "understatement", but I have no idea what OP's hoping to get by asking for a "name" for this "construction" (What construction? Are we being asked to analyse *Russian* text? Or analyse any one of an open-ended set of "rough translations" in English?)

Comment: @FF Sarcasm can't be ruled out here and may well be the more probable, but we don't want to offend any Russians.

Comment: By an unreal condition relating to the future do you mean it has not happened yet but it could (hypothetical), or that you don't believe that it will happen?

Comment: This phrase should express some scepticism and to sent message "I'm not interesting in this, but may be you have something else".